# CiviCRM Joomla Demo Site

Tags: joomla, extension, demo-site

How do we volunteer to help maintain CiviCRM demo sites, such as the one for Joomla? I noticed that an extensions directory hasn't been created and set yet and it would be cool to be able to test out extensions. How are the demo sites maintained and who is in involved? Is there a secret handshake to get involved?

http://joomla.demo.civicrm.org/administrator/

Comment: Yes, there is definitely a need for someone giving the Joomla demo some love. It now runs Jooma 3.8 (3.10 is latest in 3.x and soon unsupported, 4.0 being the current version) and CiviCRM 5.21 beta 1 (with 5.57 being the latest).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask to help out in the "infrastructure" channel on https://chat.civicrm.org!

The demo sites are automatically regenerated nightly via a script based on [civicrm-buildkit](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-buildkit) - so it's not really sufficient to change the setting.  Folks in that channel can help get others up to speed though.

Comment: Does civicrm-buildkit work with Joomla?

Comment: Kind of?  Work's been happening relatively recently to improve that.  Contact me as "junglebird" on chat.civicrm.org and I can put you in touch with the appropriate folks if you need more info.

Comment: And, if possible, couple of 'issues' to consider: fixing the build so that the Joomla version of CiviCRM is up to date? Currently it's running an older CiviCRM 4.6 build (not current). Also, I'd like to be using the current 4.7.x version so that I could cross check features.